# Best data structure for collection strings in c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a huge collection of strings. I will find out all the strings which starts with the given character more frequently. What would be a best collection to do this. I will initialize the collection in sorted order.

Thanks

Comment: What are you using the strings for?

Comment: Are you using collection of strings as suggestion list ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [search List<string> for string .StartsWith()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472881/search-liststring-for-string-startswith)

Comment: Larry, huge is like around 100,000 words minimum.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a map from a character to all strings starting with that character, you might find [**`ILookup<TKey, TElement>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/bb460184%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) suitable. It's very similar to a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/xfhwa508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), with two main differences:

1. Instead of a 1:1 mapping, it performs a 1:n mapping (i.e. there can be more than one value per key).
2. You cannot instantiate (`new`) nor populate it (`.Add(…)`) yourself; instead, you let .NET derive a fully populated instance from another collection by calling `.ToLookup(…)` on the latter.

Here's an example how to build such a 1:n map:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;  // for List<T>
using System.Linq;                 // for ILookup<TKey, TValue> and .ToLookup(…)

// This represents the source of your strings. It doesn't have to be sorted:
var strings = new List<string>() { "Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "Quux", … };

// This is how you would build a 1:n lookup table mapping from first characters
// to all strings starting with that character. Empty strings are excluded:
ILookup<char, string> stringsByFirstCharacter =
    strings.Where(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))  // exclude empty strings
           .ToLookup(str => str[0]);                  // key := first character

// This is how you would look up all strings starting with B.
// The output will be Bar and Baz:
foreach (string str in stringsByFirstCharacter['B'])
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

> <sub>**P.S.:** The above hyperlink for `ILookup<…>` (the interface) refers you to the help page for `Lookup<…>` (the implementation class). This is on purpose, as I find the documentation for the class easier to read. I would however recommend to use the interface in your code.</sub>

Comment: This does not work for my situation. Those words are not english words. Single letter will be combination of multiple alphabets. so i will be in situation to return all words if combined with others..

Comment: @Kumaran: Well, you don't *have to* map from `char` to `string`s. You could also map from `string` to `string`s, allowing you to choose arbitrarily long prefixes instead of only single characters (Unicode code points). You'd have to change the type to `ILookup<string, string>`, and you'd need to replace the `.ToLookup(…)` lambda that extracts the first character with one that extracts a string prefix.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search regularly with a huge collection of strings, then use a Hash table. Remember to distribute the table evenly to speed up  the look-up operation.

Comment: i think hashtable is not available in windows phone8

Answer (score 0):

Well so you need to create an index on function from string.

For this Id suggest using

`Dictionary<string,List<string>>` data structure.

ToLookup isn't so good cause it limits your ability to maniuplate the data structure.

Comment: i can't separate the words like this. then it will complicate my other operations.