# What is the fastest implementation of sql like 'x%' in c# collections on a key

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, collections, trie

I have a need to do very quick prefix `"sql like"` searches over a hundreds of thousands of keys. I have tried doing performance tests using a SortedList, a Dictionary, and a SortedDictionary, which I do like so :

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
// add a million random strings
var results = dictionary.Where(x=>x.Key.StartsWith(prefix));
```

I find that that they all take a long time, `Dictionary` is the fastest, and `SortedDictionary` the slowest.

Then I tried a Trie implementation from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640998/NET-Data-Structures-for-Prefix-String-Search-and-S which is a magnitude faster, ie. milliseconds instead of seconds.

So my question is, is there no .NET collection I can use for the said requirement? I would have assumed that this would be a common requirement.

## My basic test :

```
    class Program
    {
        static readonly Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>(); 
        static Trie<object> trie = new Trie<object>(); 

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var random = new Random();
            for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                var randomstring = RandomString(random, 7);
                dictionary.Add(randomstring, null);
                trie.Add(randomstring, null);
            }

            var lookups = new string[10000];
            for (var i = 0; i < lookups.Length; i++)
            {
                lookups[i] = RandomString(random, 3);
            }

            // compare searching
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            foreach (var lookup in lookups)
            {
                var exists = dictionary.Any(k => k.Key.StartsWith(lookup));
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("dictionary.Any(k => k.Key.StartsWith(randomstring)) took : {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

// test other collections

            sw.Restart();
            foreach (var lookup in lookups)
            {
                var exists = trie.Retrieve(lookup).Any();
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("trie.Retrieve(lookup) took : {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static string RandomString(Random random,int length)
        {
            const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

            return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
              .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
        }
    }
```

## Results:

```
dictionary.Any(k => k.Key.StartsWith(randomstring)) took : 80990 ms
trie.Retrieve(lookup) took : 115 ms
```

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417070/c-sharp-version-of-sql-like

Comment: So, in your case fastest was `var results = dictionary.Where(x=>x.Key.StartsWith(prefix));`?

Comment: @RenatZamaletdinov Using Regex is unlikely to be performant for this particular case.

Comment: Do you create the list once and search it many times, or will it be frequently updated?

Comment: @MatthewWatson The keys will never be updated after they are put into the collection.

Comment: @Sebastian506563 https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/10/20/text-pattern-search-trie-class-net.aspx

Comment: your test is unfair for `var exists = trie.Retrieve(lookup)` becouse you are getting query not exist resoult as bool

Comment: @Sebastian506563 its badly labelled, its actually not a bool but an IEnumerable of the actual objects stored with the keys.

Comment: @لَاإِلٰهَإِلَّاالله In that case you should call `trie.Retrieve(lookup).Any()` to ensure that the iteration code is actually run.

Answer (score 0):

If sorting matters, try to use a `SortedList` instead of `SortedDictionary`. They both have the same functionality but they are implemented differently. `SortedList` is faster when you want to enumerate the elements (and you can access the elements by index), and `SortedDictionary` is faster if there are a lot of elements and you want to insert a new element in the middle of the collection.

So try this:

```
var sortedList = new SortedList<string, object>();
// populate list...

sortedList.Keys.Any(k => k.StartsWith(lookup));
```

If you have a million elements, but you don't want to re-order them once the dictionary is populated, you can combine their advantages: populate a `SortedDictionary` with the random elements, and then create a new `List<KeyValuePair<,>>` or `SortedList<,>` from that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can sort the keys once and then use them repeatedly to look up the prefixes, then you can use a binary search to speed things up.

To get the maximum performance, I shall use two arrays, once for keys and one for values, and use the overload of `Array.Sort()` which sorts a main and an adjunct array.

Then you can use `Array.BinarySearch()` to search for the nearest key which starts with a given prefix, and return the indices for those that match.

When I try it, it seems to only take around 0.003ms per check if there are one or more matching prefixes.

Here's a runnable console application to demonstrate (remember to do your timings on a RELEASE build):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int count = 1000000;
            object obj = new object();

            var keys   = new string[count];
            var values = new object[count];

            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                keys[i] = randomString(5, 16);
                values[i] = obj;
            }

            // Sort key array and value arrays in tandem to keep the relation between keys and values.

            Array.Sort(keys, values);

            // Now you can use StartsWith() to return the indices of strings in keys[]
            // that start with a specific string. The indices can be used to look up the
            // corresponding values in values[].

            Console.WriteLine("Count of ZZ = " + StartsWith(keys, "ZZ").Count());

            // Test a load of times with 1000 random prefixes.

            var prefixes = new string[1000];

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
                prefixes[i] = randomString(1, 8);

            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
                for (int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
                    StartsWith(keys, prefixes[j]).Any();

            Console.WriteLine("1,000,000 checks took {0} for {1} ms each.", sw.Elapsed, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds/1000000.0);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<int> StartsWith(string[] array, string prefix)
        {
            int index = Array.BinarySearch(array, prefix);

            if (index < 0)
                index = ~index;

            // We might have landed partway through a set of matches, so find the first match.

            if (index < array.Length)
                while ((index > 0) && array[index-1].StartsWith(prefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    --index;

            while ((index < array.Length) && array[index].StartsWith(prefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                yield return index++;
        }

        static string randomString(int minLength, int maxLength)
        {
            int length = rng.Next(minLength, maxLength);

            const string CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(CHARS, length)
              .Select(s => s[rng.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
        }

        static readonly Random rng = new Random(12345);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, after little test I found something close enought with usage `BinarySearch` only Cons is that you have to sort keys from a to z. But the biggest the list, the slower it will be so ***Ternary Search*** is fastest from all you can actualy found with binary pc architecture.

**Method:** ([Credits shoult go to @Guffa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472881/search-liststring-for-string-startswith))

```
    public static int BinarySearchStartsWith(List<string> words, string prefix, int min, int max)
    {
        while (max >= min)
        {
            var mid = (min + max) / 2;
            var comp = string.CompareOrdinal(words[mid].Substring(0, prefix.Length), prefix);
            if (comp >= 0)
            {
                if (comp > 0)
                    max = mid - 1;
                else
                    return mid;
            }
            else
                min = mid + 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

**and test implementation**

```
        var keysToList = dictionary.Keys.OrderBy(q => q).ToList();
        sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        foreach (var lookup in lookups)
        {
            bool exist = BinarySearchStartsWith(keysToList, lookup, 0, keysToList.Count - 1)!= -1
        }
        sw.Stop();
```

[image]